# What happened to Trigger.Operation?

Tags: trigger, enum

A new enum `TriggerOperation` is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_System_TriggerOperation.htm) but no corresponding variable has been added to the Trigger Context Variables [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm). I've just found out that using API 43.0, a reference to `Trigger.Operation` (see idea link immediately below) won't compile.

The idea [A Trigger Context Enum to represent the current operation and before/after state](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003XnCQAU) that includes this example - the example not provided by Salesforce mind you - is marked as "delivered":

```
switch on Trigger.Operation {
    when TriggerOperation.BEFORE_INSERT, TriggerOperation.BEFORE_UPDATE { /* stuff */ }
    where TriggerOperation.AFTER_INSERT { /* ... */ }
}
```

**Anyone have any idea if `Trigger.Operation` or an equivalent will make an appearance in the near future?**

It's not rocket science to write code to return the `TriggerOperation` enum value, it's just a shame if everyone has to write and test their own given that it's behaviour that belongs in `Trigger`:

```
public static TriggerOperation operation() {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) return TriggerOperation.BEFORE_UPDATE;
        else if (Trigger.isInsert) return TriggerOperation.BEFORE_INSERT;
        else if (Trigger.isDelete) return TriggerOperation.BEFORE_DELETE;
    } else if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) return TriggerOperation.AFTER_UPDATE;
        else if (Trigger.isInsert) return TriggerOperation.AFTER_INSERT;
        else if (Trigger.isDelete) return TriggerOperation.AFTER_DELETE;
        else if (Trigger.isUndelete) return TriggerOperation.AFTER_UNDELETE;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the context variable `Trigger.operationType` to get current `System.TriggerOperation` enum value.

To test it with `switch`, you can use something like this.

```
trigger TestSwitch on Account (before insert, after insert) {
    switch on Trigger.operationType {
        when BEFORE_INSERT {
            System.debug('Before Insert');
        }
        when AFTER_INSERT {
            System.debug('After Insert');
        }
        when else {
            System.debug('Something went wrong');
        }
    }
}
```

Sample example with handler class can be found in Salesforce developer [blogs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/summer18-rethink-trigger-logic-with-apex-switch.html)

P.S. unfortunately,  [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) is yet not updated with enum context variable

Comment: Now I know what it is called I see it is mentioned here [Summer’18: Rethink Trigger Logic with Apex Switch](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/summer18-rethink-trigger-logic-with-apex-switch.html). Thanks!

Comment: np, glad I could help) This link is already present in my answer)

Comment: Thank for linking to my blog post! I've filed a docs bug for this missing documentation. I do link to it in the blog post, but be sure to check out the video by the PM: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailheadx/sessions?q=a2q3A000001pyRtQAI#tbd